# Performance: dynamic script injection vs server rendered scripts

Tags: javascript, performance

From performance perspective, I wanted to understand the differences between loading a piece of JS code from server (option #1) versus loading the same piece of code on the client side (option #2).

Option #1:
Server sends out the JS code in  tag.

Option #2:
Server sends out the code as a JS string (`var jsCode = '[code]'`). On the browser, after load is fired, a script node is created and the .text property is set (`scriptNode.text = jsCode`)

```
scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
document.body.appendChild(scriptNode);
scriptNode.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
scriptNode.text = jsCode;
```

With performance perspective, is one option better than other? For example, in option #2, we need to do the extra work of creating the script node and adding it to the DOM tree. Apart from these are there any differences performance (time and memory wise)?

Comment: Additionally, I tried to test this out and found different results depending on the complexity of JS code being executed. Thankfully the results were consistent across browsers. Please see [Simple JS code](http://jsperf.com/script-v-eval/4) and [Complex JS code](http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-8380204-eval-vs-script/4) examples demonstrating the difference in behavior

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some magic I don't know of, I would think there is no way option 2 could be faster - you're still sending the same amount of data over the wire, you're still parsing a script block, and you're even adding an extra step by having to modify the DOM (which of course uses some memory).

However, there could be a *perceived* performance increase in option 2 **if you load the script asynchronously**, as this won't block the page rendering during parsing like an inline script block will.